# Excel Code that limits the characters per cell to 6

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Hoping someone has an answer for me.

Im trying to generate code for Excel that produces every available alpha-numeric outcome Between T5A0A0 and T6Z9Z9 in order: letter, number, letter, number, letter, number.

This code works:

```vba
Sub GenerateOptions()
    Dim row As Long
    Dim col As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim l As Integer
    Dim m As Integer
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim cellValue As String
    
    ' Set starting row and column
    row = 1
    col = 1
    
    ' Loop through each possible combination
    For i = 5 To 6
        For j = Asc("A") To Asc("Z")
            For k = 0 To 9
                For l = Asc("A") To Asc("Z")
                    For m = 0 To 9
                        For n = Asc("A") To Asc("Z")
                            ' Combine letters and numbers into a string
                            cellValue = "T" & i & Chr(j) & k & Chr(l) & m & Chr(n)
                            ' Check if current combination is within range and has 6 characters or less
                            If cellValue >= "T5A0A0" And cellValue <= "T6Z9Z9" Then
                                ' Write string to current cell and move to next row
                                Cells(row, col).Value = cellValue
                                row = row + 1
                            End If
                        Next n
                    Next m
                Next l
            Next k
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

THE PROBLEM:

The code listed above produces results with >6 characters. Making the list INFINATE.  When i try to add the IF statement "Len(cellValue) <= 6" the code breaks.  I have tried rearranging the 'Len()' so that it is at the beginning of the IF statement:

```
If Len(cellValue) <= 6 And cellValue >= "T5A0A0" And cellValue <= "T6Z9Z9"
```

and at the end:

```
If cellValue >= "T5A0A0" And cellValue <= "T6Z9Z9" And Len(cellValue) <= 6
```

I've also nested the If statement:

```
If cellValue >= "T5A0A0" And cellValue <= "T6Z9Z9" Then
    If Len(cellValue) <= 6
```

I'm not entirely sure what else to try at this point. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted never produces strings with 6 characters due to this line of code:

```vba
 cellValue = "T" & i & Chr(j) & k & Chr(l) & m & Chr(n)
```

You are concatenating 7 variables. I suggest that :

1. You change the line above to `cellValue = "T" & i & Chr(j) & k & Chr(l) & m`
2. You remove the loop that uses the `n`

The loop using `m` will be:

```vba
   For m = 0 To 9
       
       ' Combine letters and numbers into a string
       cellValue = "T" & i & Chr(j) & k & Chr(l) & m '& Chr(n)
       ' Check if current combination is within range and has 6 characters or less
       If cellValue >= "T5A0A0" And cellValue <= "T6Z9Z9" Then
           'If cellValue.Length = 6 Then
           ' Write string to current cell and move to next row
           Cells(row, col).Value = cellValue
           row = row + 1
       End If
   Next m
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works but takes 2 minutes to complete on my PC, tried a few variations but could not find a work around:

```
Option Explicit

Sub GenerateAlphaNumericOutcomes()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
    Dim firstChar As Integer
    Dim secondChar As Integer
    Dim thirdChar As Integer
    Dim fourthChar As Integer
    Dim fifthChar As Integer
    Dim sixthChar As Integer
    
    Dim outcome As String
      StartTime = Timer
    For firstChar = Asc("T") To Asc("U") - 1
        For secondChar = 5 To 6
            For thirdChar = Asc("A") To Asc("Z")
                For fourthChar = 0 To 9
                    For fifthChar = Asc("A") To Asc("Z")
                        For sixthChar = 0 To 9
                            outcome = Chr(firstChar) & CStr(secondChar) & Chr(thirdChar) & CStr(fourthChar) & Chr(fifthChar) & CStr(sixthChar)
                            If outcome >= "T5A0A0" And outcome <= "T6Z9Z9" Then
                                Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1) = outcome
                            End If
                        Next sixthChar
                    Next fifthChar
                Next fourthChar
            Next thirdChar
        Next secondChar
    Next firstChar
    SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation
End Sub

enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

seeing as there are no VBA tags and because this was an interesting loop I thought about ways of doing it using formulae and came up with these individual columns that can then be concatenated together:

[image: screenshot of example output at top]

[image: screenshot of example output in the middle]

Column A is a hardcoded T.

Column B has the formula:

```
=MOD(ROUNDDOWN((ROW()-2)/67600,0),10)+5
```

Column C uses

```
=CHAR(MOD(ROUNDUP((ROW()-1)/2600,0)-1,26)+65)
```

Column D is:

```
=MOD(ROUNDDOWN((ROW()-2)/260,0),10)
```

Column E is:

```
=CHAR(MOD(ROUNDUP((ROW()-1)/10,0)-1,26)+65)
```

and Column F is:

```
=MOD(ROW()-2,10)
```

Column G then is just a CONCAT of the previous columns.

This takes ~1s to fill down from row 2 to 135,201 and calculate.